# why is nan can be prevented by duplicated calculation?

Tags: c, crash, nan

Sometimes I've got a nan as a result of multiplication no-nan b and c:

```
double a = b * c; //b = 0, c = 1024, a = nan
```

or as a result of floor():

```
double a = floor(b); //b = 2024, a = nan
```

Duplicated calculation and usage of sleep() prevent this issue:

```
a = b * c;  //a = nan
a = b * c;  //a = 0

a = floor(b);  //a = nan
a = floor(b);  //a = 2024

sleep(1);
a = b * c;  //a = 0

sleep(1);
a = floor(b);  //a = 2024
```

**CPU** is AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 3400+

**CPU temp**:

```
k8temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Core0 Temp: -1В°C
Core0 Temp: -2В°C
Core1 Temp: +3В°C
Core1 Temp: +7В°C

Adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter at 0b00
M/B Temp:    +30В°C  (low  =    +0В°C, high =   +85В°C)   
CPU Temp:  +28.5В°C  (low  =  +0.0В°C, high = +85.0В°C)   
M/B Crit:    +85В°C  (hyst =   +75В°C)                  
CPU Crit:   +124В°C  (hyst =  +114В°C)
```

May this issue be the result of CPU timing features? Or is there another causes of the issue?

**UPDATE**

I found out the following program produce nan on that machine:

```
double a, b, c;
while(1) {
   a = 0;
   b = 1024;
   c = a * b; //c will be nan within 10-20 sec.
}
```

Comment: Now this is strange, indeed.

Comment: This definitely seems like a machine specific issue. Are you overclocking it? What temperature is it running at?

Comment: NAN means "not a number", it is what illegal floating point operations return. None of the cited qualify.

Comment: I find it very unlikely that you'd get NaN from a simple multiplication unless one of the numbers is either: 1) a NaN, or 2) the multiplied result is out of the range (1E+/-308 or so). Either your input data is bad, processor running outside specs [overclocked, not enough cooling, bad memory, etc].

Comment: @MatsPetersson Even then: aren't modern implementations of floating-point arithmetic supposed to handle overflow as Inf?

Comment: Yes, probably right, you get +/-INF if it overflows. If it underflows, I'm not sure - zero?

Comment: I have to add that I have been using AMD processors for the past 17 years, almost exclusively, often both at work and at home, and not had anything similar to this. My current two Linux machines are using X2 and X4 versions similar to yours (Models 265 and 965 respectively) and my laptop is a dual core 3400 if memory serves right). If your processor regularly gets floating point multiplies wrong, you'd definitely notice - everything displayed in your web-browser is most likely calculated with floating point, for example.

Comment: How do you actually check the contents of that variable?  If I was a compiler, I would be likely to optimize all that code away.  Who else uses `c`?  What's the point in calculating it?  It should always be zero if nobody else uses `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's hardware specific issue. The following program on the current platform works 10-20 sec:

```
#include <math.h>
int main() {
   double a, b, c;
   while (1) {
      a = 0;
      b = 1024;
      c = a * b;
      if (isnan(c)) break;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW: do you `#include <math.h>` ? My gcc generates inline code without math.h, and a call to __isnan with <math.h>

Comment: @wildplasser, yes, math.h should be included. Edit my post.

Answer (score 5):

Any chance you have a stack or memory overwrite occuring from elsewhere in the program - bad thread handling or bad handled mutex?  Adding a sleep to "fix" the problem makes me think it could be a concurrency issue.  If possible, debug the values and see if they change on the fly from other locations with a write to memory break point or perhaps just some printfs (which might change the timing of the problem and hide it as well.)

Comment: The fastest way to (dis)prove this is to just try your scenario in isolation. If you're still getting the same issues when the entire program is your example, you're in trouble.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Code was checked by valgring. It hasn't found anything. These variables are local.

Comment: The variables being local means nothing if you've done something bad with threads or the like. `valgrind` is a good, but not definitive check. Do you get the stated problem if your entire code is that as stated in the question?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Actually, I've got that issue at libresample library.

Comment: @Alex Could it be possible that your RAM is defect? Did you try to compile your code with optimizations enabled? Are there any warnings by the compiler if you compile with -Wall?